# Geocoding on OSM shapefiles via Elasticsearch

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, ogr2ogr, elasticsearch

I want to get a geocoding system based on OSM data and Elasticsearch engine. I've tried some projects like komoot\photon, but, as I'm a really newbie in this, I stuck on preparing of the data for my area and many troubles with a Nominatim server.

I could be using the whole world dump of indices but it is too big data for me(about 56Gb space). However, I found out I can use just Elasticsearch from scratch and some tool such as ogr2ogr which provide a support of a files converting from shape to elasticsearch. So, I downloaded shapefiles from geofabrik and converted some of them to Elasticsearch.

What kind of shapefiles (points, roads, places...) should I import to Elasticsearch for organize simple geocoding?

I'm thinking of using it on my Leaflet HTML page.

And what kind of requests should be to work with Elasticsearch engine then?

Answer (score 2):

The [Pelias Geocoder](https://mapzen.com/pelias/) from mapzen runs on elasticsearch, and uses OSM data by default, though it can use any data source. The importers are split into separate modules, so even if your not interested in using the pelias geocoder, you may still find the [OSM importer](https://github.com/pelias/openstreetmap) useful.

On another note: Shapefiles of OSM data are probably not what you want for source data, there are several sites that produce extracts as shapefiles, but the data is far more readily available in PBF format, and the PBF files are faster to process.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse! I'll certainly tale a look on that. I've just noticed it work on Node.js and I've never used it before. Can I use it on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, node works on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/kiselev-dv/gazetteer/tree/develop/Gazetteer
It will create you a json index for osm file.

And you could use https://github.com/kiselev-dv/gazetteer/tree/develop/GazetteerWeb as an example of geocoder based on ElasticSearch

Comment: Hi, Dmitry! Thanks for your solution. I just want to clarify. I've download json dump from http://tr1.nowtaxi.ru/dumps/ and what I should do in next step?

Comment: There are bunch of objects in file. Each line contains one object encoded as JSON object. Objects are `adrpnt` - addresses, `poipnt` - POIs, `hghway` - streets and so on. Every object contains information about object itself, and about higher address levels. You could upload them directly to ES or take a look at GazetteerWeb.

Comment: OK! If I want to take a look on GazetteerWeb how can I import json data there?

Comment: Start it, and get `localhost:8080/api/info.json` it will return metadata about available api and parameters. To import data, you need `localhost:8080/api/location/_import?source=/path/to/dump.osm.gz&drop=true&osmdoc=true` It will asks you for a password. Password sha1 is in `conf/dev/environment.properties`

Comment: Great! Thanx, Dima! I'll try it

Comment: You could mail me for further details, my email is in my profile.